# CryptoJS equivalent of PyCrypto

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I'm trying to user CryptoJS under node to decrypt messages. I've got working Python code for decrypting the messages, but I need to run this under nodejs and would rather not call out to python for every message.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import base64

encrypted='tBIFLLdvl/Bp8XAwXBYatbJSYkNTl9/dXkHZd4OjbZ0I9Jg6xrAx/bxuQHuZrNSzYZOBEKbyMlTTT8nQEDza8wQ22mrRaZlQqT3aWpdZe6aiWAEIvTHoQPglgVbz1HnYOHfZtGmu3a3cwfpFMK+ouczTWM545nWvG/I4zV4uFgna1rW9sznxumN/3RKSbC1USZ2TM9PrG967M5Mu+riQfh9i/yt6ubwj3kln2+C0WsRRr44ELyDKGdS69YExa535z42bfXTORjvaiMvizvkz55c343s0G4ziT6tLfDCGELsrAu/2NViKxJZZRg8Dmm0FnchB9OQ4ujVCBoDUXvfx3iHjzquC+OftbOovQUecoXb7UfuwIxMekgSJnonLC45S'
key = '22<\\09\\8e.==\\4#{{+!%i=]%Y/upi8!Z'
iv = '{+!%i=]%Y/upi8!Z'

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
print cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(encrypted))
```

This prints out my decrypted string from python. I'm sure my CryptoJS version is completely wrong at this point.

```
var node_cryptojs = require('node-cryptojs-aes');
var CryptoJS = node_cryptojs.CryptoJS;
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('22<\\09\\8e.==\\4#{{+!%i=]%Y/upi8!Z');
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('{+!%i=]%Y/upi8!Z');
var encrypted = 'tBIFLLdvl/Bp8XAwXBYatbJSYkNTl9/dXkHZd4OjbZ0I9Jg6xrAx/bxuQHuZrNSzYZOBEKbyMlTTT8nQEDza8wQ22mrRaZlQqT3aWpdZe6aiWAEIvTHoQPglgVbz1HnYOHfZtGmu3a3cwfpFMK+ouczTWM545nWvG/I4zV4uFgna1rW9sznxumN/3RKSbC1USZ2TM9PrG967M5Mu+riQfh9i/yt6ubwj3kln2+C0WsRRr44ELyDKGdS69YExa535z42bfXTORjvaiMvizvkz55c343s0G4ziT6tLfDCGELsrAu/2NViKxJZZRg8Dmm0FnchB9OQ4ujVCBoDUXvfx3iHjzquC+OftbOovQUecoXb7UfuwIxMekgSJnonLC45S';
var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ ciphertext: encrypted }, key, { iv: iv } );
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.stringify(plaintextArray));
```

All I get out of this version is a bunch of garbled text such as

```
{)¬L¶u[?®º[ «)þd0³(Á¨ÕßgÙä  Þ¨Þêâí99dáb*¦ÿßqf pr£Æ(> þ?C×$ÀM#<o¬_±À¥s=ê,)u<¯XÚîDÊP¢q|fÌ½^IiaJÂ__NîjbÉâïðp8å.º}ÜucósLÈqÁè&ô£LYLüâÙháë
```

Comment: why are you doing the Latin1 stuff in the js? .... (sorry no idea about js in general)

Comment: You haven't shown us sample key, IV or ciphertexts. This is almost certainly an encoding issue and not just one. Latin1 seems out of place. `encrypted` is probably Base64 encoded, so it must be decoded before passing it into `decrypt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was one encoding away from correct. The Latin1 parses are correct. It was just the decode from base64 on the input that was missing. Must have missed that combination earlier.

```
var node_cryptojs = require('node-cryptojs-aes');
var CryptoJS = node_cryptojs.CryptoJS;
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('22<\\09\\8e.==\\4#{{+!%i=]%Y/upi8!Z');
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('{+!%i=]%Y/upi8!Z');
var encrypted = 'tBIFLLdvl/Bp8XAwXBYatbJSYkNTl9/dXkHZd4OjbZ0I9Jg6xrAx/bxuQHuZrNSzYZOBEKbyMlTTT8nQEDza8wQ22mrRaZlQqT3aWpdZe6aiWAEIvTHoQPglgVbz1HnYOHfZtGmu3a3cwfpFMK+ouczTWM545nWvG/I4zV4uFgna1rW9sznxumN/3RKSbC1USZ2TM9PrG967M5Mu+riQfh9i/yt6ubwj3kln2+C0WsRRr44ELyDKGdS69YExa535z42bfXTORjvaiMvizvkz55c343s0G4ziT6tLfDCGELsrAu/2NViKxJZZRg8Dmm0FnchB9OQ4ujVCBoDUXvfx3iHjzquC+OftbOovQUecoXb7UfuwIxMekgSJnonLC45S';
var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted) }, key, { iv: iv } );
console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.stringify(plaintextArray));
```